# DataTime.parse.utc.to_s output in jRuby 1.7 and ruby 9

Tags: ruby, string, jruby, string-conversion

I have a code:

```
value = DateTime.parse(value.to_string).utc.to_s
```

Input(value) is timestamp value fetched from database and the parsed as value to this code.
which was giving output

> 2012-04-01T04:00:00+00:00

in jruby 1.7

after upgrading jruby to version 9 it gives the output as :

> 2012-04-01 04:00:00 UTC

for the same input.

How would I align in the new jruby version?
I would appreciate any input on this.

Comment: how is `value` defined? please update your question so we know what your input is

Comment: updated, value is of datatype timestamp fetched from oracle db

Comment: If you need a _specific_ format, use `strftime`, not `to_s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this and it worked

```
format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
value_1 = DateTime.parse(value.to_string).utc.to_s
value_2 = DateTime.parse(value_1, format).to_s
```

- value : Thu, 16 Apr 2020 13:34:29 -0700
- value1  : 2020-04-16 20:34:29 UTC
- value2 : 2012-04-16T20:34:29+00:00